# Ubuntu 22.04 RAM Speed Doesn't Match Configured Memory Speed

Tags: ram

I have DDR4-3600MHz CL16 RAM, but after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I cannot get it to run faster than 2100MHz. I've tried enabling and re-enabling both XMP profiles in the bios, but nothing is working.

My CPU is an Intel 12700k, and my motherboard is an ASUS TUF GAMING Z690-PLUS WIFI D4. From the docs and what I read online, I should be able to get 3600MHz.

Here is the output when I run `sudo dmidecode --type 17`:

```
Handle 0x004C, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0048
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Controller1-ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2100 MT/s
    Manufacturer: G Skill Intl
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: F4-3600C16-16GVKC   
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 3600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.35 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 5, Hex 0xCD
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 16 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521434/dmidecode-for-ram-info-which-speed-is-real-speed-info), your memory *is* running at 3600 Hz. See the following line, which holds *actual* memory speed:

```
Configured Memory Speed: 3600 MT/s
```

The `Speed: 2100 MT/s` line just states the official highest speed supported by the DIMM, but not the speed it's actually running at, which can be higher than the "highest supported speed" when XMP is enabled.